# Ctrl click on src element of ui:include doesn't navigate

Tags: eclipse, jsf-2, facelets, jsf-2.2, eclipse-luna

Clicking on path of a ui:include src attribute doesnt navigate in Eclipse Luna + jsf2.2 + primefaces5.1 .

I have tried it with the latest jboss tools html editor and while ctrl click on java classes works, the same click on src attribute values doesnt.

Answer (score -2):

Be sure to NOT use the proper java ee 6 namespace for ui namespace

```
xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
```

...instead use the old one

```
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
```

Comment: That's not a solution. That's a workaround. You'd better improve the answer to make that clear. The way how your answer is currently formulated incorrectly gives the impression that using the new XML namespace is very bad, and is therefore misleading to starters. It's not the new XML namespace causing the problem. It's the IDE/plugin itself who is buggy and needs to be fixed/updated.